# Is checking if algorithm that solves NP problem running in polynomial time NP problem itself?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, formal-languages

input - correct algorithm A that solves NP class problem, algorithm runs in O(f), is O(f) polynomial?

Let's check with new algorithm B if A runs in polynomial time

what can we say about complexity of this problem?

Comment: Do you have a proof that the algorithm solves the problem ? (if not then add to the algorithm a piece of code searching for a counter-example to the consistency of ZFC)

Comment: assumption is that A is correct (will halt)
do you mean that B have halt problem even if A is correct?

Comment: Sure. Say $A(x)$ runs in $O(length(x)^k)$, then let $C(x)$ be the program enumerating the $length(x)$ first theorems of ZFC and check if one contradicts another, if so enumerate the integers up to $2^{length(x)}$, then return $A(x)$. Since we assume that ZFC is consistent then $C(x)$ solves the same problem as $A$ and runs in polynomial time too. But we have no proof that ZFC is consistent, thus no proof that $C$ runs in polynomial time.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the output?

Comment: simple decision - yes/no

Comment: "Yes", if $A$ runs in polynomial time for every input, regardless if it correct, and "No" if there is a sequence of inputs for which $A$ does not run in polynomial time?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker 

example:
let's say _**A**_ is bruteforce 3-SAT solving algorithm, we don't care about the input _**x**_  _**A**_ takes, we only know that it will solve 3-SAT.
 
_**B**_ takes _**A**_ implementation, and decides weather _**A**_ runs in polynomial time or not, based only on _**A**_ implementation, without simulating it. In this example of _**A**_ being bruteforce 3-SAT, _**B**_ returns No.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker 
But as reuns mentioned - undecidable problem reduces to it.